# Cannot change Borderbursh and borderthickness of Listpicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone, listpicker

When I set this Listpicker like this, only the background changes, the borderbrush and borderthickness do not change. I don't know why...

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding Genrelist}" DisplayMemberPath="Genre" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index}" Background="#BF22A1DC" BorderBrush="#FFE61C1C" BorderThickness="20"/>
```

Comment: Are you using WP7 or WP8? Do you not get the border and brush set when the ListPicker is collapsed or when it is expanded? What is your goal? How many items do you have in Genrelist? I have tried this with 3-4 hardcoded items and it works for me on WP8.

Comment: I use Wp8 and I have 4 Item in Genrelist.... i want to get this when LIstpicker is in both case. Thanks for u help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would make rather just comment but i dont have enough reputation. Anyway from your information its not clear where is the problem i guess there is something on page that overrides these properties. But as a suggestion try Blend (in VS2012: View=>Open in Blend..) and try create template(right click on component and the Edit Template=>Edit and Copy..) from ListPicker and then check out template in XAML of page if there is something that might cause this problem.